# Unable to acces and store plots

Tags: r, plot

I try to get plots for  Kernel density estimates for kernel discriminant analysis, I use next code:

```
library("MASS")
install.packages("rgl")
install.packages("misc3d")
install.packages("mvtnorm")
install.packages("KernSmooth")
install.packages("ks")
library("ks")
library("MASS")
library("ks")
data("iris")
ir <- iris[,1:3]
ir.group <- iris[,5]
Hpi1 <- Hkda(x = ir, x.group = ir.group, bw = "plugin",
pilot = "samse", pre = "sphere")
Hpi2 <- Hkda.diag(x = ir, x.group = ir.group, bw = "plugin",
pilot = "samse", pre = "scale")
Hscv1 <- Hkda(x = ir, x.group = ir.group, bw = "scv", pre = "sphere")
Hscv2 <- Hkda.diag(x = ir, x.group = ir.group, bw = "scv", pre = "scale")
#As of ks 1.8.11, kda.kde has been subsumed into kda, so all prior calls to kda.kde can be replaced
#by kda. To reproduce the previous behaviour of kda, the command is kda(, kde.flag=FALSE)
#
kda(x = ir, x.group = ir.group, Hs = Hpi1)

kda(x = ir, x.group = ir.group, Hs = Hpi1, kde.flag=FALSE)

install.packages("scatterplot3d")
library(scatterplot3d)
scatterplot3d(iris[,1:3],color=c("red","blue","green")
[iris$Species], col.axis="blue", col.grid="lightblue",
main="scatterplot3d",pch=20,cex.symbols=2)
iris.f1<-kda(x = ir, x.group = ir.group, Hs = Hpi1)
iris.f2<-kda(x =ir,x.group = ir.group, Hs = Hscv1)

plot(iris.f1)
plot(iris.f2)
```

But when I get till `plot(iris.f1)`, rgl device shows me four graphics in several seconds, I can't get them all. I tried to use `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`, but it doesn't help.
Please, help me to understand, why can't I get all these graphics, what I am doing wrong, or what I should do more to get all these graphics.

Answer (score 0):

The plot makes the desired graphics the problem is they close when the new one is generated. You can store them by opening a pdf and storing there the plots.

```
pdf("Plots1.pdf", title="Plots Iri 1") #Opens the pdf
plot(iris.f1)
dev.off() #To close the opened pdf
pdf("Plots2.pdf", title="Plots Iri 2")
plot(iris.f2)
dev.off() #To close the opened pdf
```

This will create 2 pdf with the plots one for each page in the working folder (To know which is type `getwd()`)

---

You found the following:

```
for(i in 1:3){ #Previously there are three different plots
   pdf(paste("plot", i,".pdf",sep=""))#Creates the pdf
   plot(cbind(iris[1],iris[i])) #Join all the plots in one
   dev.off() } #Close the pdf and the iteration
```

What this piece of code do is joint the plots that are stored in the pdf, to adapt to your code, maybe you need to do the following, although it is almost the same I posted before:

```
pdf("Plots.pdf", title="Plots Iris")
plot(cbind(iris.f1, iris.f2))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank You for your help, but I can't open this pdf, if I try to open it before run dev.off() , I get error message: This file is already open or is in use by another application, but when I run dev.off()  and then try to open pdf, I get another error message: This file can not be opened, because it has no page. Please, tell me how can I open this PDF!

Comment: Yes you should open after closing with dev.off. Until then it is still creating the file. What is the exact error when you open it after `dev.off()`? Could you copy it here? I used this several times  and I didn't have any problem. But maybe you need to specifically say to print in the pdf the plot...

Comment: I tried more times, but got this error message again and again:There was an error opening the document. This file can not be opened, because it has no page.

Comment: Strange, there might be a function that mask the `plot` from the base R. But sorry to say it I can not help further than this.

Comment: Hope that someone would help in that problem, I spent really a lot of time to find in google why that can happen, but I haven't resolved this problem yet.

Comment: One thing I wander is if you really need all the packages, maybe there is a conflict between them, and I hope you don't reinstall each time you run the code the initials packages

Comment: may be I reinstalled packages several times, because worked with both R versions(2.15.2 and 3.0.2), but I don't reinstall them each time when I run the code, what is interesting, I found in internet small code:    'for(i in 1:3){
  pdf(paste("plot", i,".pdf",sep=""))
  plot(cbind(iris[1],iris[i]))
  dev.off()
}'
and it works in my computer, but I can't find the way, how can I get there my iris.f1 graphic

Comment: I will answer later, now I can't (probably in 5h or more)

Comment: tried code with your corrections but after I run "> pdf("Plots.pdf", title="Plots Iris")
> plot(cbind(iris.f1, iris.f2))
" I get message "dev.off() #To close the opened pdf". And I can't open PDF file.